# Any faster, simpler alternative to php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, preg-match

I am using cakephp 1.3 and I have textarea where users submit articles. On submit, I want to look into the article for certain key words and and add respective tags to the article.

I was thinking of preg_match, But preg_match pattern has to be string. So I would have to loop through an array(big).

Is there a easier way to plug in the keywords array for the pattern.

I appreciate all your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest treating your array of keywords like a hash table. Lowercase the article text, explode by spaces, then loop through each word of the exploded array. If the word exists in your hash table, push it to a new array while keeping track of the number of times it's been seen.

I ran a quick benchmark comparing regex to hash tables in this scenario. To run it with regex 1000 times, it took 17 seconds. To run it with a hash table 1000 times, it took 0.4 seconds. It should be an O(n+m) process.

```
$keywords = array("computer", "dog", "sandwich");
$article = "This is a test using your computer when your dog is being a dog";
$arr = explode(" ", strtolower($article));
$tracker = array();

foreach($arr as $word){
    if(in_array($word, $keywords)){
        if(isset($tracker[$word]))
            $tracker[$word]++;
        else 
            $tracker[$word] = 1;
    }
}
```

The $tracker array would output: "computer" => 1, "dog" => 2. You can then do the process to decide what tags to use. Or if you don't care about the number of times the keyword appears, you can skip the tracker part and add the tags as the keywords appear.

**EDIT:** The keyword array may need to be an inverted index array to ensure the fastest lookup. I am not sure how in_array() works, but if it searches, then this isn't as fast as it should be. An inverted index array would look like

```
array("computer" => 1, "dog" => 1, "sandwich" => 1); // "1" can be any value
```

Then you would do isset($keywords[$word]) to check if the word matches a keyword, instead of in_array(), which should give you O(1). Someone else may be able to clarify this for me though.

Comment: thanks for a quick response. It works fine when there are no xhtml tags. But mine has xhtml tags in the article. Is there way to workaround it.

Comment: Hmm, then regex may not be completely avoidable. You could apply strip_tags() to the article string before lowercasing it. That should take care of all XHTML tags. There may be a small impact on the speed though.

Comment: This is almost the same I did using array_count_values() and str_word_count().. :)
@JoshR Do you need to strip XHTML tags too? Because you didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you should just use [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

You will still need to loop through the array of words, but `strpos` is much, much faster than `preg_match`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you could try matching all the keywords using one single regexp, like `/word1|word2|word3/`, but I'm not sure it is what you are looking for. And also I think it would be quite heavy and resource-consuming.

Instead, you can try with a different approach, such as splitting the text into words and checking if the words are interesting or not. I would make use of `str_word_count()` using someting like:

```
$text = 'this is my string containing some words, some of the words in this string are duplicated, some others are not.';
$words_freq = array_count_values(str_word_count($text, 1));
```

that splits the text into words and counts occurrences. Then you can check with `in_array($keyword, $words_freq)` or `array_intersect(array_keys($words_freq), $my_keywords)`.

If you are not interested, as I guess, to the keywords case, you can `strtolower()` the whole text before proceeding with words splitting.

Of course, the only way to determine which approach is the best is to setup some testing, by running various search functions against some "representative" and quite long text and measuring the execution time and resource usage (try `microtime(TRUE)` and `memory_get_peak_usage()` to benchmark this).

**EDIT:** I cleaned up a bit the code and added a missing semi-colon :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look for multiple words from an array, then combine said array into an regular expression:

```
 $regex_array = implode("|", array_map("preg_escape", $array));
 preg_match_all("/($regex_array)/", $src, $tags);
```

This converts your array into `/(word|word|word|word|word|...)/`. The arrray_map and preg_escape part is optional, only needed if the $array *might* contain special characters.

Avoid strpos and loops for this case. preg_match is faster for searching after alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr)

> If given two arguments, the second
>   should be an array in the form
>   array('from' => 'to', ...). The return
>   value is a string where all the
>   occurrences of the array keys have
>   been replaced by the corresponding
>   values. The longest keys will be tried
>   first. Once a substring has been
>   replaced, its new value will not be
>   searched again.

Comment: strtr is nice but Josh isn't looking for replacing but for searching.

Comment: Oh, I thought he wanted to replace the keywords with links to the tag or something.

Answer (score 0):

Add tags manually? Just like we add tags here at SO.